# R: Drop all rows that fulfill a certain condition

Tags: r

I am trying to clean up a `dataframe`. I've created an indicator variable that is 1, 0, or -1.
For instance:

```
Name   Indicator_1
A      1
B      0
C      1
D     -1
```

Now I am trying to drop all rows that are >0, giving me a `dataframe` like this:

```
 Name   Indicator_1
    B      0
    D     -1
```

So far, I've tried a couple of different approaches, including:

```
df <- df[df$Indicator_1 > 0,]
df <- df(df, select = -c(Indicator_1 >0))
df <- df %>% slice(-c(Indicator_1 >0))
df <-df[!(df$Indicator_1 >0),]
```

Unfortunately, none of these approaches work as intended. Either all entries become `NA` or nothing happens.

Am I looking at this the wrong way? I'd appreciate any help and don't have a package preference.

Edit: Some of the `Indicator_1` entries are `NA` themselves.

Edit: Added repex

```
structure(list(Name = c("K", "L", "Y", 
"S", "R", "W"),Indicator_1 = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What is the issue with the first case `df[df$Indicator_1 > 0,]`  Do you have a a numeric column in Indicator_1

Comment: Can you supply `dput(df)`? It's important to see how data is stored in that object and what all the relevant classes are. It's not really easy to know what it is just looking at the printed output. Your first code works just fine with `df <- data.frame(Name=c("A", "B", "C", "D"), Indicator_1=c(1, 0, 1, -1))`

Comment: It introduces several NA observations (rows) and doesn't drop the rows we want to have dropped

Comment: Some of the Indicator_1 entries are NA. Does that change anything?

Comment: @questionmark. Yes. that changes things. What do you want to do with those values. Are they greater than 0 or not to you? Probablt `df <- df[which(df$Indicator_1 > 0),]` will work fine for you.

Comment: try `df[as.numeric(as.character(df$Indicator_1))>0,]`

Comment: That also introduces a lot of NA rows. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: @questionmark I think you may have some strings in your column, which gets converted to NA with `as.numeric` i.e. `as.numeric(c(1, 2, 'hello', 3, 4))`

Comment: For some reason, trying the most intuitive approach that you've provided (subset(df, Indicator_1 >0 & !is.na(Indicator_1))) makes all entries NA.

Comment: @questionmark can you show the dput of a small subset of data

Comment: dput() just froze R. I am not sure how else I can provide a small subset.

Comment: I would use `dput(droplevels(head(df)))`

Comment: In the dput output, it is all NA for the Indicator_1 and it is a numeric.  So, I guess my solution should have worked on it

Answer (score 1):

If it is a numeric column, then the methods should work.  If there are `NA` elements, create a logical condition with `is.na`

```
subset(df, Indicator_1 >0 & !is.na(Indicator_1))
#   Name Indicator_1
#1    A           1
#3    C           1
```

If it is not `numeric` class and it doesn't have any character string, we can use `type.convert` to change the `class`

```
subset(type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE), Indicator_1 >0 & !is.na(Indicator_1))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Name = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), Indicator_1 = c(1L, 
0L, 1L, -1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

### 1) Make an example **df**

```
  set.seed(42) # the answer to the universe
  df <- data.frame(
  Name = rep(letters[1:20], 5),
  Indicator_1 = sample(
    c(1, 0, -1, NA),
    size = 100,
    replace = TRUE,
    prob = c(.3, .3, .3, .1)
    )
  )
  nrow(df)
  #[1] 100
```

### 2) Clear out NA results

```
df_complete <- df[complete.cases(df), ]
nrow(df_complete)
#[1] 84
```

### 3) Double check *Indicator_1* is numeric

```
df_complete$Indicator_1 <- as.numeric(df_complete$Indicator_1)
str(df_complete)
# 'data.frame' :    84 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ Name       : chr  "c" "d" "e" "f" ...
# $ Indicator_1: num  1 0 0 -1 0 1 0 0 -1 0 .
```

### 4) Perform the filter you have already provided us with

```
df_filtered <- df_complete[df_complete$Indicator_1 <= 0, ]
nrow(df_filtered)
#[1] 56
head(df_filtered)
#    Name  Indicator_1
# 4     d           0
# 5     e           0
# 6     f          -1
# 7     g           0
# 9     i           0
# 10    j           0
```